# Database Result Output Spooling

Tags: java, database, file, select, output

How do I spool EACH row result from a single SELECT sql statement to different output file?
For instance, if I have

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnId < 45;`

```
while (rs.next()) { 
  result of row1 goes to row1.txt; 
  result of row2 goes to row2.txt; 
  result of row3 goes to row3.txt; 
  result of row4 goes to row4.txt;
}
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What programming languages do you have available?

Comment: Am using the oracle Database and am programming in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way (not production quality code, but a basic idea):

```
private String spoolRow(ResultSet currentRow) 
{
    // Append each attribute to a StringBuilder in a nicely formatted way 
    // and return.
}

private void myMethod(....)
{
    ...
    ...
    FileOutputStream fos;
    String fileName;
    int counter = 1;
    while (rs.next()) {
        fileName = "row" + counter + ".txt";
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(spoolRow(rs));
        fos.close();
        counter++;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

If you also need the column header, then `ResultSetMetaData` from `resultSet.getMetaData()` can be used to get the column names, prepare the header and write it to every file before writing the data row.

Comment: Nice option. Will try this out to see. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: This solves the problem at hand. Thanks a lot.

I have been trying to rate the answer as the best but can not get the link. Can you please provide a clue on how to do this?